# Storing REGEX in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex, associative-array

I'm using an array to store a regex expression like this:

```
private $rules = ['usuario' => ['regexp' => "^(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$", 'length' => ['max'=>'30','min'=>'4']],
    'email' => ['length' => ['max'=>'70','min'=>'5']],
    'contrasena' => ['length' => ['max'=>'70','min'=>'4']]
];
```

When I try:

```
echo '/' . $this->rules['usuario']['regexp'] . '/';
```

I got:

```
/^(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?
```

Can anybody explain this behavior?

Comment: view source, its all there, its just the browser no showing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that there are `<` symbols in the regexp, and in the browser they are interpreted as tags. To avoid such behavior, you can escape such characters via `htmlspecialchars`:

```
echo htmlspecialchars('/' . $this->rules['usuario']['regexp'] . '/');
```